# Currency with 5 decimal digits?

Tags: delphi, precision, floating-accuracy

I need to translate following C# code into Delphi:

```
decimal XYZ = decimal.Round(dataset123.XYZ, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

The result will be saved into a float field in a MSSQL Database.

When I work with `double` in Delphi, there are several problems since it is no fixed decimal. Also, when saved into the ADO database, the database viewer often shows a extremely long number because it has too many digits. Additionally, there seems to be a rounding method issue, where the rounding is not always done "away from zero".

I want to fix the most severe problem for now. I *need* a 5-digit currency, but Delphi only has the data type `currency` which has 4-digits. Having a 5 digit value is an important requirement for this kind of project / business process.

At some internet sources, I read that people talk about such a code:

```
var
  x: Decimal[5,3]
```

But this syntax isn't valid for me. I work with Delphi 2007.

Is there anything I can do to get a 5-digit fixed decimal?

Comment: Write your own type based on Int64

Comment: Try my [Decimal](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/decimals.html) type. It is compatible with the .NET Decimal type, so your code should be easy to port.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And how do I do that? I tried `type C = 0.00000 .. 99999.99999;`, but that doesn't work. I do not understand why an Integer can help defining a decimal.

Comment: Also see [BCD](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Data.FmtBcd.TBcd).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks, I will try this. I am not sure how I will pass this to ADO, maybe as string. But at the moment I am facing problems with Delphi 2007 compatibility. For the line `PLongword(@Result)[0]` it says "Array type expected". I have no idea what [0] of a Pointer is supposed to do. Also, `UStrFromPWCharLen` and `{$POINTERMATH ON}` are undefined.

Comment: @Daniel That's a different issue for a separate question

Comment: Is your MySQL datatype already defined or are you free to set/change that?

Comment: @JanDoggen I know that the ADO-stuff is a different question. I will try to figure that database stuff out, after I have found a solution in Delphi to make a 5-decimal number even possible. That's harder than expected. In MSSQL, I have an already defined table structure using the type "Float"

Comment: Fixed point arithmetic is often implemented on top of integer types. You have a fixed implicit offset.  So, 100000 equals 1.00000.

Comment: If your Int64 is scaled by 100000, then you can use Int64 or a suitable type as fixed point type. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: @Daniel: pointer math does not work in D2007. You would have to modify the code a little to make it work in D2007. FWIW, P[0] is the first item pointed to, P[1] is the next, etc. See [This DocWiki article](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirspointermath_xml.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code using David Heffernan's suggestion to show you how to get started:

```
unit UnitMyCurrency;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMyCurrency = record
    Value : int64;

    class operator implicit( pValue : integer ) : TMyCurrency;
    class operator implicit( pValue : single ) : TMyCurrency;
    class operator implicit( pValue : TMyCurrency ) : single;

    class operator Add( p1 : TMyCurrency; p2 : TMyCurrency ) : TMyCurrency;
    class operator Subtract( p1 : TMyCurrency; p2 : TMyCurrency ) : TMyCurrency;

    class operator NotEqual( p1 : TMyCurrency; p2 : single ) : boolean;
  const
    cFactor = 100000;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyCurrency }

class operator TMyCurrency.implicit(pValue: integer): TMyCurrency;
begin
  Result := pValue * cFactor;
end;

class operator TMyCurrency.implicit(pValue: single): TMyCurrency;
begin
  Result := round( pValue * cFactor);
end;

class operator TMyCurrency.Add(p1, p2: TMyCurrency): TMyCurrency;
begin
  Result := TMyCurrency( p1.Value + p2.Value );
end;

class operator TMyCurrency.implicit(pValue: TMyCurrency): single;
begin
  Result := pValue.Value / cFactor;
end;

class operator TMyCurrency.NotEqual(p1: TMyCurrency; p2: single): boolean;
begin
  Result := TMyCurrency( p2 ).Value <> p1.Value;
end;

class operator TMyCurrency.Subtract(p1, p2: TMyCurrency): TMyCurrency;
begin
  Result.Value := p1.Value - p2.Value;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  v1, v2, v3 : TMyCurrency;
begin
  v1 := 5.12345;
  v2 := 6.00000;
  if (v1 + v2 ) <> 11.12345  then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
  end;
end;

end.
```

Obviously it is not complete, but when finished you would have a new type that does what you need and that you have complete control over.

The following shows how to use overloaded operators. It is for Seattle, but nothing has changed since 2007.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)

Comment: @David Heffernan - Thanks for the edit - and sorry for getting your name wrong.

Answer (score -3):

The easy way is to use the variable [`CurrencyDecimals`](http:////docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.CurrencyDecimals).
Something like that:

```
var
  price: Double;

begin
  price:= 1234.56789;
  CurrencyDecimals := 5;
  ShowMessage('Price = '+Format('%m', [price]));
end;
```

Comment: That's a binary floating point type, and the asker wants fixed point decimal.

Comment: Yes and :) ? I am still thinking that the best way to achieve what the asker want is to convert the value to the wanted fixed point value. Furthermore 
this leaves how the value is stored and his visual representation.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully appreciate the distinction between binary floating point, and fixed point decimal

Comment: Be reassured David, I am aware

Comment: @Samz: I agree with David: recommending a binary floating point type to replace a fixed point type like Currency makes me also think you don't quite see the problems that would introduce and which the asker wants to avoid.

Comment: I understand, but i just disagree with the use of a fixed point decimal and all the work you have to do for converting an integer to a fpv.

Comment: If you think that the user is solving their problem in the wrong way, leave a comment to that effect. But the question is quite explicit about demanding the use of a decimal data type.

Comment: OP actually invites a these troubles with some sort of extent, because he writes floating point to storage engine and changes to fixed point (which is proper solution in this case) only for presentation. So this makes answer valid for **temporary** fix, IMO.

Comment: Hmm, good point, if asker is already mixing float and decimal then he's got bigger problems

Comment: Not only is this a program wide setting, it was deprecated and I believe now removed. Further, this code makes a string, and nowhere in the question is there mention of strings. Sympathy voting at its worst.